# What is postUrl in: AlbumEntry insertedEntry = myPicasa.insert(postUrl, myAlbum);

Tags: android, api, picasa

I´m trying to understand and use the Picasa Api, I´m using this example https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java?hl=nl-NL,
so I´m trying to create a new album using the followin code:

```
AlbumEntry myAlbum = new AlbumEntry();

    myAlbum.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(title));
    myAlbum.setDescription(new PlainTextConstruct(description));

    AlbumEntry insertedEntry = myPicasa.insert(postUrl, myAlbum);
```

Now is my question, how do I find the postUrl, or what do I have to fill in there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the linked documentation, `postURL` seems to be the ID of the album into which the photo needs to be inserted. It can be constructed in Java thus:

```
URL albumPostUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/username/albumid/albumid");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to add an album.

```
URL postUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/" + username);
```